# MongoDB: very slow queries inside index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I've seen number of similar questions, but they didn't resolve my issue ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250172/unreasonably-slow-mongodb-query-even-though-the-query-is-simple-and-aligned-to), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720535/slow-mongodb-query-can-you-explain-why), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734962/simple-mongodb-query-very-slow-although-index-is-set)).

I have collection with almost 2M documents. My problem: very simple query (find({id: 53})) runs almost 5 minutes (see everything related info below).

I tried to add index by the "id" field, tried to hint, *scanAndOrder* is false. I have anough memory (for now no swap and only 600MB totaly is used on server (still about 1GB is free)). It is debian 7 and mongodb 2.4.7.

Maybe this matters: yesterday I ran repairDatabase and after that noticed the issue (but I cannot say for sure if it was before). But anyway I ran full validate on the collection and everything seems to be ok. Also yesterday I added one more index ({id: 1}). Also today I reindexed the collection.

During all such long queries my disk is used very extensively.

```
> db.results.count()
1819411

> db.results.stats()
{
    "ns" : "spider.results",
    "count" : 1819411,
    "size" : 26662218768,
    "avgObjSize" : 14654.313273911172,
    "storageSize" : 28309077856,
    "numExtents" : 34,
    "nindexes" : 4,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 207245248,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 53144000,
        "datetime_-1" : 45793776,
        "id_1_datetime_1" : 62513696,
        "id_1" : 45793776
    },
    "ok" : 1
}

> db.results.getIndices()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "spider.results",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "datetime" : -1
        },
        "ns" : "spider.results",
        "name" : "datetime_-1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "datetime" : 1
        },
        "unique" : true,
        "ns" : "spider.results",
        "name" : "id_1_datetime_1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "spider.results",
        "name" : "id_1"
    }
]

> db.results.validate(true)
{
    "ns" : "spider.results",
    "firstExtent" : "0:258000 ns:spider.results",
    "lastExtent" : "18:2000 ns:spider.results",
    "extentCount" : 34,
    "extents" : [
        {
            "loc" : "0:258000",
            "xnext" : "0:25a000",
            "xprev" : "null",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 8192,
            "firstRecord" : "0:2580b0",
            "lastRecord" : "0:2598b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "0:25a000",
            "xnext" : "0:29d000",
            "xprev" : "0:258000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 274432,
            "firstRecord" : "0:25a0b0",
            "lastRecord" : "0:29c6b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "0:29d000",
            "xnext" : "0:3a9000",
            "xprev" : "0:25a000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 1097728,
            "firstRecord" : "0:29d0b0",
            "lastRecord" : "0:3a6c30"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "0:3a9000",
            "xnext" : "0:7d9000",
            "xprev" : "0:29d000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 4390912,
            "firstRecord" : "0:3a90b0",
            "lastRecord" : "0:7d8ab0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "0:7d9000",
            "xnext" : "0:d81000",
            "xprev" : "0:3a9000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 5931008,
            "firstRecord" : "0:7d90b0",
            "lastRecord" : "0:d7fcb0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "0:d81000",
            "xnext" : "0:1524000",
            "xprev" : "0:7d9000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 8007680,
            "firstRecord" : "0:d810b0",
            "lastRecord" : "0:15238b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "0:1524000",
            "xnext" : "0:1f74000",
            "xprev" : "0:d81000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 10813440,
            "firstRecord" : "0:15240b0",
            "lastRecord" : "0:1f73ab0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "0:1f74000",
            "xnext" : "1:2000",
            "xprev" : "0:1524000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 14598144,
            "firstRecord" : "0:1f740b0",
            "lastRecord" : "0:2d5f6b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "1:2000",
            "xnext" : "1:12ce000",
            "xprev" : "0:1f74000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 19709952,
            "firstRecord" : "1:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "1:12cd8b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "1:12ce000",
            "xnext" : "1:2c2f000",
            "xprev" : "1:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 26611712,
            "firstRecord" : "1:12ce0b0",
            "lastRecord" : "1:2c2eab0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "1:2c2f000",
            "xnext" : "1:4e72000",
            "xprev" : "1:12ce000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 35926016,
            "firstRecord" : "1:2c2f0b0",
            "lastRecord" : "1:4e719b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "1:4e72000",
            "xnext" : "2:2000",
            "xprev" : "1:2c2f000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 48500736,
            "firstRecord" : "1:4e720b0",
            "lastRecord" : "1:7cb27b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "2:2000",
            "xnext" : "2:3e74000",
            "xprev" : "1:4e72000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 65478656,
            "firstRecord" : "2:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "2:3e71d30"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "2:3e74000",
            "xnext" : "3:2000",
            "xprev" : "2:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 88399872,
            "firstRecord" : "2:3e740b0",
            "lastRecord" : "2:92c1ab0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "3:2000",
            "xnext" : "3:71d2000",
            "xprev" : "2:3e74000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 119341056,
            "firstRecord" : "3:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "3:71d1ab0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "3:71d2000",
            "xnext" : "3:10b78000",
            "xprev" : "3:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 161112064,
            "firstRecord" : "3:71d20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "3:10b70ab0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "3:10b78000",
            "xnext" : "4:2000",
            "xprev" : "3:71d2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 217501696,
            "firstRecord" : "3:10b780b0",
            "lastRecord" : "3:1dae29b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "4:2000",
            "xnext" : "4:11809000",
            "xprev" : "3:10b78000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 293629952,
            "firstRecord" : "4:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "4:118088b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "4:11809000",
            "xnext" : "5:2000",
            "xprev" : "4:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 396402688,
            "firstRecord" : "4:118090b0",
            "lastRecord" : "4:29212930"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "5:2000",
            "xnext" : "5:1fe5d000",
            "xprev" : "4:11809000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 535146496,
            "firstRecord" : "5:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "5:1fe5ca30"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "5:1fe5d000",
            "xnext" : "6:2000",
            "xprev" : "5:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 722448384,
            "firstRecord" : "5:1fe5d0b0",
            "lastRecord" : "5:4af553b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "6:2000",
            "xnext" : "7:2000",
            "xprev" : "5:1fe5d000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 975306752,
            "firstRecord" : "6:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "6:3a21d6b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "7:2000",
            "xnext" : "8:2000",
            "xprev" : "6:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 1316667392,
            "firstRecord" : "7:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "7:4e7ab0b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "8:2000",
            "xnext" : "9:2000",
            "xprev" : "7:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 1777504256,
            "firstRecord" : "8:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "8:69f278b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "9:2000",
            "xnext" : "10:2000",
            "xprev" : "8:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 2146426864,
            "firstRecord" : "9:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "9:7fefdab0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "10:2000",
            "xnext" : "11:2000",
            "xprev" : "9:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 2146426864,
            "firstRecord" : "10:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "10:7feff630"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "11:2000",
            "xnext" : "12:2000",
            "xprev" : "10:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 2146426864,
            "firstRecord" : "11:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "11:7feffa30"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "12:2000",
            "xnext" : "13:2000",
            "xprev" : "11:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 2146426864,
            "firstRecord" : "12:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "12:7feffb30"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "13:2000",
            "xnext" : "14:2000",
            "xprev" : "12:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 2146426864,
            "firstRecord" : "13:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "13:7fefb7b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "14:2000",
            "xnext" : "15:2000",
            "xprev" : "13:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 2146426864,
            "firstRecord" : "14:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "14:7feffb30"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "15:2000",
            "xnext" : "16:2000",
            "xprev" : "14:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 2146426864,
            "firstRecord" : "15:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "15:7fefba30"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "16:2000",
            "xnext" : "17:2000",
            "xprev" : "15:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 2146426864,
            "firstRecord" : "16:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "16:7feff9b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "17:2000",
            "xnext" : "18:2000",
            "xprev" : "16:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 2146426864,
            "firstRecord" : "17:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "17:7feff9b0"
        },
        {
            "loc" : "18:2000",
            "xnext" : "null",
            "xprev" : "17:2000",
            "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
            "size" : 2146426864,
            "firstRecord" : "18:20b0",
            "lastRecord" : "18:1f8328b0"
        }
    ],
    "datasize" : 26662218768,
    "nrecords" : 1819411,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "padding" : 1,
    "firstExtentDetails" : {
        "loc" : "0:258000",
        "xnext" : "0:25a000",
        "xprev" : "null",
        "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
        "size" : 8192,
        "firstRecord" : "0:2580b0",
        "lastRecord" : "0:2598b0"
    },
    "lastExtentDetails" : {
        "loc" : "18:2000",
        "xnext" : "null",
        "xprev" : "17:2000",
        "nsdiag" : "spider.results",
        "size" : 2146426864,
        "firstRecord" : "18:20b0",
        "lastRecord" : "18:1f8328b0"
    },
    "objectsFound" : 1819411,
    "invalidObjects" : 0,
    "bytesWithHeaders" : 26691329344,
    "bytesWithoutHeaders" : 26662218768,
    "deletedCount" : 14,
    "deletedSize" : 1617742528,
    "nIndexes" : 4,
    "keysPerIndex" : {
        "spider.results.$_id_" : 1819411,
        "spider.results.$datetime_-1" : 1819411,
        "spider.results.$id_1_datetime_1" : 1819411,
        "spider.results.$id_1" : 1819411
    },
    "valid" : true,
    "errors" : [ ],
    "ok" : 1
}

> db.results.find({id:6}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor id_1_datetime_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 47402,
    "nscannedObjects" : 47402,
    "nscanned" : 47402,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 47402,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 47402,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 248,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 254485,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "id" : [
            [
                6,
                6
            ]
        ],
        "datetime" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "ip-10-137-56-52:27017"
}
```

The only thing I haven't done yet is backup with repair and then restore. But I am not sure it will help...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Searching for that `id` returns 47 thousand documents. Is that what you expect?

Comment: It's also a very large database -- 28GB? Are you sure that your system has enough memory for the working set? Loading 47000 documents given average document size would mean it's loading about 650MB of data.

Comment: As a side note, it's never necessary to create an index on `_id` because Mongo does that automatically. Or, maybe you have another field just called `id`

Comment: Thanks. Really DB is big and also there should exist a lot of documents with the same "id" field. There are enough resources on the machine too as I can see in the **htop**.

But unfortunately it seems here is my fault. Firstly I played around with similar query ({id: 5, revision: 1}) which didn't have index. It took about 10 minutes (and returned nothing). Explain of this query took approx. the same time.

Then I tried explain of query {id:5} (with index). It took 5-7 minutes depending on the ID. But real query without explain runs fast - as I found later. Sorry for waisting your time :(

Comment: So my conclusion is: explain time of the query is not the same is real execution time of the query.

Comment: No explain time is the time of that explain not of the query

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the example query you give for an id of 6 matches 47402 documents:

```
> db.results.find({id:6}).explain()
    "n" : 47402,
```

and the average document size is about 14654 bytes:

```
> db.results.stats()
    "avgObjSize" : 14654.313273911172,
```

Does this match your view of the situation?

This means that the results from this query will be about 662 MB in
size. If the 662 MB of documents returned by the query are not in
memory and must be fetched from disk then a lot of disk activity will
result and the query will take a long time.

There are a few ways you could improve performance, depending on your
application requirements:

- use a more specific query that matches fewer documents, for example
  use _id to fetch a single document or specify a datetime as well as
  an id in your query.
- refactor your document schema to make the documents you wish to query smaller.
- use a projection in the query to select only a subset of the 14KB
  document to return and build an index that contains the fields in that
  query projection, so that the query can be satisfied entirely from the
  index. Note however that this will only work if you select a small
  enough subset of the document so that your index does not grow to be
  large, putting you back in the same situation of having to page the
  index in from disk. The db.results.stats() output tells you how big
  your indexes are.
- equip your server with enough memory so that the collection will remain
  entirely in memory. The collection size is about 26 GB so you would
  need at least that much memory for this approach:

  > db.results.stats()
  >       "size" : 26662218768,

Hope this helps,

Bruce

Comment: Thanks for your really helpful answer. Documents are big because I save in some of them a lot of text content (not in all) - maybe I should move them do another collection and only save references. But as I commented above, I found real reason of slow explain and that's why my question is resolved for now (time of the explain is not time of the real query).

Comment: Keep in mind as you interpret your timing experiments that you will see different times for the same operation depending on whether the information is currently in memory. For example, if you do query that returns 600MB of results, the first time it will be slow because it has to read the 600MB from disk, but the second time it will be fast because that 600MB will be in memory. The same may apply when you compare explain() results and find() results.